# what's the meaning of "#define __cdecl" in my C++ code?

Tags: c++, cdecl

I'm working on an existing c++ project with visual studio, and I found out that almost every function declaration gets a `__cdecl` in front of the function name, like:`void __cdecl functionName()`. Then I jump to the definition of `__cdecl`, which locates in the `winnt.h` file:

```
#if (_MSC_VER >= 800) || defined(_STDCALL_SUPPORTED)
#define NTAPI __stdcall
#else
#define _cdecl
#define __cdecl
#define NTAPI
#endif
```

I've searched [cdecl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/cdecl?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=msvc-170) and got that it's the default calling convention for C and C++ programs, but code above tells me that `__cdecl` extends to nothing. So why place a `__cdecl` before function name as it's just nothing ? or did I misunderstand the code above?

Comment: The *compiler* treats the `__cdecl` declarations. It’s not (and cannot be) defined in the language, hence the macro is empty.

Comment: See that `#if` and its condition? If that condition is true, then the compiler might have those as extended keywords.

Comment: The Microsoft compiler uses `__cdecl` as a calling convention. For other compilers it can be defined as nothing.

Comment: The URL in this answer redirects to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/cdecl?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=msvc-170 - but the edit queue was full and I couldn't update it.

Comment: 32-bit code has multiple calling conventions, __stdcall is another common one.  You found the 64-bit definition of it, x64 was a clean design that no longer distinguishes between cdecl and stdcall.  So that's why the #define is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what's the meaning of #define __cdecl”

Lines that begin with `#` are preprocessor directives. `#define` is a directive that defines a preprocessor macro. `#define __cdecl` defines a macro with identifier `__cdecl` and empty replacement. If such macro is defined, the processor will replace all instances of the `__cdecl` with an empty string.

> So why place a __cdecl before function name as it's just nothing ?

Take a look at the directives at the beginning of the definition in question:

> ```
> #if (_MSC_VER >= 800) || defined(_STDCALL_SUPPORTED)
> #else
> ```

The macro is defined **conditionally**. When the macro is not defined, `__cdecl` will not expand to nothing. When not expanded to nothing, `__cdecl` is a microsoft specific function specifier as you have discovered.

The conditionally defined macro allows one to write code that uses `__cdecl` on systems that allow it, and automatically remove it on systems that do not.

> But I'm still confused with the #if (_MSC_VER >= 800) || defined(_STDCALL_SUPPORTED) line, what does it mean?

It is a preprocessor directive that test whether the macro `_MSC_VER` has greater value than 800, or if macro `_STDCALL_SUPPORTED` is defined. If the test is false, then the code between #if and #else is removed. If it is true, then the code between #else and #endif is removed.

Comment: I see. So it's a way to comment `__cdecl` under certain conditions. But I'm still confused with the `#if (_MSC_VER >= 800) || defined(_STDCALL_SUPPORTED)` line, what does it mean?

Comment: @Mark: `_MSC_VER` is only defined by the Microsoft Visual C compiler, and contains its version number. This is a check if compilation is done on the Microsoft compiler (Version 8 or later), or a compiler declaring `_STDCALL_SUPPORTED`. They will use `__stdcall` and `__cdecl`; other compilers won't.

Answer (score 0):

It means that if an API is defined as using NTAPI it will generate code that uses the __stdcall calling convention - a variation of the Pascal calling convention in which the callee cleans the stack.  With __cdecl, the caller cleans the stack (so it supports variadic type functions).

And all of this is conditional on the `#if (_MSC_VER >= 800) || defined(_STDCALL_SUPPORTED)`